# React native: Undefined is not an object

Tags: reactjs, react-native

I'm making a react native app with expo and I'm having some trouble parsing the response data from the api. Below is a sample response from the api and my goal is to retrieve `main` from the weather array. I can log weather array just fine but when I put `state.weather[0].main` it throws the undefined object error.

```
Object {
  "clouds": Object {
    "all": 20,
  },
  ...,
  "weather": Array [
    Object {
      "description": "few clouds",
      "icon": "02d",
      "id": 801,
      "main": "Clouds",
    },
  ],
}
```

Below is my code, I fetch from the api on `useEffect()` hook. At first the logs shows undefined but after fetching it logs correctly except for `state.weather[0].main`. I just started react native coming from Android, I hope you guys could help me, I'm stuck for a day now. Thanks

```
const HomeScreen = ({ navigation }) => {
  const { state: { defaultCity } } = useContext(CitiesContext);
  const { state: { weather }, fetchWeather } = useContext(WeatherContext);    

  useEffect(() => {
    if (defaultCity) {
      fetchWeather(defaultCity);
    }
  }, []);

  console.log(weather);
  console.log(typeof (weather[0]));
  console.log(weather[0]);
  console.log(weather[0].main);

  return (
    <View style={styles.container}>
      <LinearGradient
        // {...weatherBgProvider[weather.weather.main]}
        colors={['#000', '#fff']}
        style={styles.gradient}
      >
        <SafeAreaView
          style={{
            position: 'relative'
          }}
          forceInset={{ top: 'always' }}
        >
          <View style={{ marginTop: Header.HEIGHT, flex: 1 }}>
            <Text >{JSON.stringify(state)}</Text>
          </View>
        </SafeAreaView>
      </LinearGradient>
    </View>
  );
};
```

Comment: In your console log you get undefiened?

Comment: @behzad at first load, but when after fetching i can log all. That is without the `state.weather[0].main` log, do i need to check if it's not undefined before logging?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you are trying to log data in your render, you can do it like this:

```
<View>{This.state.weather[0] && console.log(this.state.weather[0]) }</View>
```

So you check it to exist before you log data 
Hope you get the idea and works for you

**update**

If your main not working, first try to parse your object into array like this:

***first way*** use lodash (npm i --dev lodash) and import it in your project

```
Import _ from "lodash";
```

Const newdata= _.compact(Object.values(yourobject))

And then you can use `newdata` and i think your problem will be solved

***second way*** use `_.mapKeys(yourdata,"id")` and put new data in your variable like `const newdata`

I hope it works

Comment: hello I can log it now, this is the object
`Object {
  "description": "few clouds",
  "icon": "02d",
  "id": 801,
  "main": "Clouds",
}` but if i try to log `state.weather[0].main` it still says undefined is not an object

Comment: @Ralph try this as well : {this.state.weather[0] && this.state.weather[0].main && console.log(this.state.weather[0].main)    see if its works

Comment: @Ralph i updated my answer if you needed alternative ways, good to hear your problem solved

Comment: It's 2019, why use lodash when vanilla JS has that functionality? At the least only import the lodash functions used so tree shaking can occur and JS bundle size is reduced, lodash is a beast. `import compact from 'lodash/compact';` and `import mapKeys from 'lodash/mapKeys';`.